# PHP Twig starter Problems (doesn't find templates)

Tags: php, templates, twig, template-engine

My google foo as at its limits :/. I hope you can help me. Twig can't find my templates and I iterated through a lot of random internet finds :D.

It works, when I visit the index.php (uncomment the last line), but it doesn't when I visit webserver.tld/control/xyz/sitename.php.

#### Following structure:

- ./index.php
- ./lib/Twig/{Twig stuff}
- ./control/xyz/{sitename.php, other files...}
- ./templates/categoryA/{sitename.phtml, other files...}

#### index.php

```php
require_once 'lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();
$template_dir = 'templates/categoryA';
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem($template_dir);
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array('debug' => true,));
// echo $twig->render('sitename.phtml', array('name' => 'Rapunzel'));
```

#### /control/xyz/sitename.php

```php
require_once '../../index.php';
$template = $twig->loadTemplate($template_dir . '/sitename.phtml');
echo $template->render(array('name' => 'Rapunzel'));
```

#### The Error message

```php
Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Loader' with message 'The "templates/categoryA" directory does not exist.' in /asdf/asdf/TEST_twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php on line 94
```

#### What I've tried

I tried to load several templates via an array (as argument of the Twig_Loader_Filesystem) and additionally I tried $loader->addPath() without success :/.

Comment: If you set the template path to  `__DIR__.'/templates'`, every template become relative from here, meaning if you have a template in : `__DIR_.'templates/categoryA/template1.html'`  then your render call would be like: `$twig->render('categoryA/template1.html');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, why it didn't work earlier. My "solution" now works. But it might not be a good one :D.

**index.php**

```
require_once 'lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();
$template_dir = (
    __DIR__.'/templates/categoryA',
    __DIR__.'/templates'
);
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem($template_dir);
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array('debug' => true,));
```

**sitename.php**

```
require_once '../../index.php';
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('sitename.phtml');
echo $template->render(array('name' => 'Rapunzel'));
```